# subtract or substract

Tags: terminology

Subtract is considered the only correct verb, while substract is considered wrong or at least "very" obsolete. However, here is a guy, whose mother tongue is obviously English, and who uses substract all the time https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XH-ha8va91o&index=6&list=PLNUL7DzXzp_J4TztZYOVtayTfp0DV1z5H
so I think that one can use either verb.

Is that the case?

Comment: His mother tongue certainly isn't English. It appears he has a German accent.

Comment: He is not a native speaker.  Also, I have never heard some say substraction...ever.

Comment: Fair enough. Not being a native English speaker myself, I'm not able to place his accent. (I was surmising Glasgow?) He also has a peculiar way to pronounce most v's as w's. Anyway, I agree that the currrent correct verb is subtract, but there were times, in the XVIIIth century, when substract was correct too.

Comment: Glasgow is considered native speaker.  In any case, perhaps it was used in the 18th century but most would consider using it an error in modern communication.  Good question, though.  Perhaps someone will have an answer with some interesting facts.

Comment: You're right! He is German. In his lesson 8, at time 1 mn 35 sec, we can see his whole computer screen, and it's all in German. The guy is obvioulsy quite smart, with a wanting classical education (he says "arithmetric" instead of "arithmetic"). Education and intelligence are two different things. Which is to be preferred when it's one or the other is left to anyone to choose.

Comment: I think I've heard it once or twice, but always from someone whose pronunciation was poor in several other ways.

Comment: It's French and German and possibly others. It's not English.

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Online Dictionary states that the verb [**substract**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/substract) is **now nonstandard and rare** meaning the following:

> [With object] and without object **Mathematics = subtract**.

Now, if you search the word **substract** in [Mathematics StacExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=substract), you have 618 results and [substraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=substraction) 115 results while [subtract](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=subtract) has 11,277 results and [subtraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=subtraction) 2,576 results respectively.

Some people are using the words regardless of whether they are nonstandard or rare. You can't stop people from using them and you never know how they will get traction in the future.

One thing for sure is **to substract** is synonymous with to subtract.

Note: I should have posted it in the comment, but it is too long.

Comment: But *substraction* appears to be currently used in some legal and chemistry contexts, and may be a common "alternate" spelling in India.  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=substraction&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubstraction%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

Being French native and having also some Latin background "substract and substraction" sound really good, on the other end if I use subtract or subtraction,
something is missing.   I guess time will tell....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/420189)